# Aws free trial expired

Tags: amazon-web-services

One year ago I have created an AWS free trial account and I haven't used it yet. Will it charge anything? Now I have suspended my account by myself. Will it be a problem? Can I create a new AWS account now with the same email or credit card details?

Comment: Those who downvoted should have left a commend on why they did it. My best guess is that this is something you should look up from AWS documentation (start from here https://aws.amazon.com/free/terms/) or if you have special requests then write AWS support.

Comment: What is the question? Yes you can create a new AWS account but you didn't need to suspend the previous one - if you were using resources that you were receiving for free as part of the trial, you would have to pay for them either way after trial. Some things are also always free under the AWS free tier

Answer (score 1):

#### Understand the AWS Free Tier

The AWS Free Tier provides customers the ability to explore and try out AWS services free of charge up to specified limits for each service. The Free Tier is comprised of three different types of offerings, a 12-month Free Tier, an Always Free offer, and short term trials. Services with a 12-month Free Tier allow customers to use the product for free up to specified limits for one year from the date the account was created.

More information about Free tier can be found here: [AWS Free Tier FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/free/free-tier-faqs/)

If you did not use any of the services, or if you terminated/removed your resources before the end of the free trial and did not you didn't exceed the free tier limits you won'`t be charged.

#### Can I use the same email twice?

AWS does not allow the same email id across more than one AWS accounts, even if you close the AWS account associated with the email id. You can reopen your account following this doc [Can I reopen my closed AWS account](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/reopen-aws-account/)

#### Can I use my credit card in different accounts?

For the credit card, you will not have problems to use with multiple AWS accounts.

---

If you need help you can try to contact the AWS support [here](https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/).